# Make a bold text in Android Java activity and call it

Tags: java, android, html, string

I want to make a bold text in my activity and show it in a dialog box.
I did it (I think) but I don't know how should I call it in my dialog box.

I'm trying in with HTML format:

```
    String text = "<b>" + "My text" + "</b> " + "is bold";
    StringCharacterIterator tv = null;
    tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text ));
```

Here it should work, but how can I call the "tv"?

I'm trying this way:

```
builder.setMessage(tv);
```

...but isn't working since the error is:

```
error: incompatible types: Spanned cannot be converted to String tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom dialog box(example: [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)) and set your string like below.

```
String text = "<b>My text</b> is bold";
TextView tv = yourdialog.findViewById(R.id.ur_text_view_id);
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try. But how can I set a TextView in a dialog box in Java and assign it an ID without creating a dialog layout? I would like to use the material design

Answer (score 0):

I answer by myself:

```
builder.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>Write something" + "</b> " + "here"));
```